# Package Management in Python 3.3 - what are the best tools to use?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python and am using it in a very small XML parsing script. I have become totally confused as to the various Python versions, and their package managers.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10, which appears to come with both Python2.7 and Python3.3 pre-installed from a fresh installation.

Outside of a virtualenv I have access to both versions from the prompt:

```
>which python
/usr/bin/python

>which python2
/usr/bin/python2

>which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

the first two are symlinked to the same python2.7 binary and the third to a python3.3 binary. Which all makes perfect sense.

I also understand that python3.3 comes with pyvenv for creating virtualenvs for python3.3

```
>pyvenv-3.3 mynewproject
```

creates a new virtual environment with a bin directory and a "self-contained" python3.3 interpreter and etc. To use this environment I just:

```
>source <path-to-mynewproject>/bin/activate
```

All fine and understood. Makes perfect sense. Now though comes the confusion. Do I use easy_install? Pip? Setup.py? Distribute? What are all these myriad package managers? Where do I get them? Do they work with Python2.7 or Python3.3? Or Both? Which ones will work in my new virtualenv? Do I care?

In short, given that I am only ever going to be doing Python3.3+ development, but given also that I don't want to break my system which undoubtedly needs Python2.7 packages, what is the canonical (best, approved, supported) way for me to do package management.

Seriously, what the heck? Totally confused.

Thanks for all your forth-coming assistance.

Comment: Suggested reading: [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging - The Packaging Ecosystem](http://guide.python-distribute.org/introduction.html#the-packaging-ecosystem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Isolate everything with virtualenvs
2. `pip` and `easy_install` are both package managers you can use both of them but I prefer pip
3. `setup.py` is just a script for distutils, `pip` and `easy_install` both use `setup.py` to install packages.

If you run your python in virtualenvs, it will prevent you from uninstalling or updating packages that will break your system. Then the choice between pip and easy_install isn't so clear. In theory `pip` is newer but for some reasons the way they install packages might work on pip and not on easy_install. These problems happen when you have to deal with native libraries that have to be compiled... It's hard to say which one is better but the one that works should do the trick since they are installing package in the same directory anyway.

There is no real need to install packages with `setup.py` unless they aren't available in `pypi`. `pip` also happens to install packages with `setup.py` if you pass it the directory where it is located.

If you make a package, make sure it's installable with distutils using `setup.py`. Then you can release it to `pypi`.

Also, as I know many tutorials aren't using virtualenvs and might even write inside their tutorials things like:

```
sudo pip install ..
sudo easy_install ..
```

Note that if you're using virtualenv you should never have to use sudo, and if you do use sudo, it's possible that it will install the package system wide as it won't be runned from the user in virtualenv but from root.

Suggested reading by [Lukas Graf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599111/lukas-graf) : http://guide.python-distribute.org/introduction.html#the-packaging-ecosystem

Comment: Given the complexity of the Python packaging situation, this is a very good answer - I couldn't have written a useful answer in so few words ;-)

Comment: @Loic - many thanks. Do I need a different version of Pip for Python2.7 and Python3.3? Do I install it only once, so that if used outside of a virutalenv it will install packages to system-wide but if virtualenv is activated it will install only to that env? Is that how it works or do I need to configure Pip for use with virtualenv? thanks again

Comment: @user3231690 when you create a virtualenv, it should install pip byitself. Yes that's how it works. Also one note, if you see tutorials asking for `sudo pip ...` if you're in a virtualenv, don't use sudo. `sudo` will change the user to `root` and install system wide.

Comment: @LukasGraf I guess there are lots of small nuances.

Comment: "There is no real need to install packages with setup.py unless they aren't available in pypi" is not quite correct in its implications: You can also use `pip any_path/package_dir_to_be_installed` to install something that you've downloaded from any place on the net, or even created locally. Therefore when I create a new virtualenv or venv (on non-ubuntu systems) I bootstrap first easy_install then I easy_install pip.

Comment: @Loic - thanks again, when I used pyvenv-3.3 to setup my venv it appears not to have installed Pip. I guess I need to install it manually, but is there a different version for Python2.7 and Python3.3?

Comment: @user3231690 there should be a different version. But when you `activate` a virtualenv, it will add the python env `bin` directory to your path. Check with `which pip`.

Comment: @cfi that is platform dependent I guess, virtualenv on OSx installs pip by default. On linux it might work otherwise but you can always install pip later anyway. The `setup.py` can be used to install the package as development where it installs an egg-link instead of installing the package. I wanted to keep the answer as simple as possible. like `python setup.py develop` isn't the same as `python setup.py install`. It has its purpose pip doesn't give you that power as far as I know.

Comment: I have installed python3-pip and from within an active venv I have run pip3 install pymongo. It didn't work because it needs to be run under sudo. Gives the error "could not create /usr/lib/python3.3/...". When run as sudo it works fine and installs. Why is it installing pymongo globally? From within the venv it should only install in local lib/sites-packages ??? This is most confusing and appears not to work the way intended which is THE CARDINAL SIN of software. How can package management be so darn messy and broken?

Comment: When you activate a virtual env, it works only from the terminal that you're using. You probably did not run pip3 install pymongo from the venv. Do `which pip3` to be sure and activate the virtualenv and retry without sudo. Activating only activate the virtualenv for the terminal you're using and you have to activate it everytime. Check that pip3 is located in the venv you want to use.

Comment: @loic - I have followed your instructions to the letter. I first made sure all pip's where purged from the system **outside** the venv. Then I activated the venv and ran sudo apt-get install python3-pip. It installed. Then still inside the venv I do which pip3 and I get /usr/bin/pip3. Clearly this venv and pip is broken on ubuntu 13.10. Makes me mad this. Clearly not working as intended.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47119/discussion-between-loic-faure-lacroix-and-user3231690)

Comment: @Loic: Your reply to my comment is beside my point: You state in your answer that you need to use setup.py to install a package not on PyPi. My point is that you can do that with pip as well. Since you seem to slightly prefer pip over the others, you might want to rephrase that one sentence about having to use setup.py for packages not on the cheeseshop.

Comment: @cfi there I added it.